# Can a module have an infinite number of compositions series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is there an example of a module that has an infinite number of composition series? I would think not, if there is it would have to have an infinite number of submodules.

Comment: But it is perfectly possible for a module to have an infinite number of submodules - e.g., $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module! Or are you asking about *finitely generated* modules only?

Comment: Well yeah, I can't think of an example of a finite dimensional module with an infinite number of submodules, a module with an infinite number of composition series would necessarily be such a module. What I need to find is the former, although I can't even find an example for the latter, which should be easier.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}$ (as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module) has infinitely many submodules. $1\Bbb{Z}$, $2\Bbb{Z}$, $3\Bbb{Z}$, ...

Comment: But $\mathbb Z$ doesn't have even a single composition series.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}$ is finite-dimensional as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module and has an infinite number of submodules. I agree it has no composition series. (Your question would make more sense if you dropped the second sentence, I think.)

Comment: What is "dimension"? I meant it as length.

Comment: Oh, apparently $\mathbb R^2$ does the trick, just take any subspace of dimension 1.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}$ has length $1$.

Comment: @dREaM: you've answered your own question! Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @RobArthan thank you for the suggestion, I shall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb R^2$ as a module (vector space) over $\mathbb R$ and notice that For every dimension $1$ subspace $L$ we have the composition $0\subset L \subset \mathbb R^2$.